# Iterate over list in Google Apps script ans set SUM formula

Tags: google-apps-script, iteration, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of rows stored in an index that updates frequently. At the moment the rows stored in my index are the following:

`[5.0, 11.0, 20.0, 23.0, 33.0, 40.0, 44.0, 49.0, 52.0, 27.0]`

These rows are filled with numbers which I would be liked to be summed in my row n°4.

I have tried the following :

```
for (var x=0; x<index.length;x++){

       var totalgeneral = sheet1.getRange(4,14,1,100)
        var k = index[x]
        totalgeneral.setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[1]C[0]:R["+k+"]C[0])")
}
```

However all it does is sum the 10 rows bellow my fourth row as it is the number of rows in my index. How do I iterate so that it sums only the rows in my list?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is rewriting the formula during each iteration. The `SUM` formula accepts multiple arguments, which should be separated by comma. Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  to convert all elements to `RC` notation and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them:

```
const formulaArguments = [5.0, 11.0, 20.0, 23.0, 33.0, 40.0, 44.0, 49.0, 52.0, 27.0]
  .map(k => `R[${k}]C[0]`).join();
totalgeneral.setFormulaR1C1("=SUM("+formulaArguments+")")
```

Comment: Thanks I tried adding that to my iteration. I placed the C[0] in my SUM function rather than in my map because it would not accept it. but I keep getting "ReferenceError: R is not defined". I'm not sure what to do because I'm not used to using map()

Comment: @Julie-Anne I edited the solution a few seconds after posting. Try the latest version. Read about map from the links in my post.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster I've recently gotten back into this and realised what was missing for your suggestion to work. My Google Sheet functions work with a semicolon seperator, thus I simply added it to the join like so : 
`var formulaArguments = index.map(k => `R${k}C[0]`).join(';')`
And it worked like a charm. Thanks very much for your help!